# How to set the b-pagination's main color?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-vue

In [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination#pagination) pagination there is no slot for change main color of pagination.

[image]

you see there is only blue color for it.

is there any way to change it to my required color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it by changing the `CSS` of the active item of `b-pagination`. I illustrated the solution by the following code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      rows: 100,
      perPage: 10,
      currentPage: 1
    }
  },

})
```

```css
.customPage.page-item.active .page-link {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" page-class="customPage"></b-pagination>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used deep css Selectors for this , just add a custom class to the component and select child elements accordingly (this works for vue2)

```css
::v-deep .customPagination  .page-link {
      background: #1E1E1E ;
      color: white;
      border: #363636 1px solid;
    }
    ::v-deep .customPagination .active button{
      background: #2196f3;
    }
```

```html
<b-pagination
        v-model="page"
        class="customPagination"         
      >
   </b-pagination>
```